# Regex to test that a string contains both upper case and lower case letters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a Regex to test that a string contains both upper case and lower case letters.
I found a few threads on this but and they suggest using a forward lookup, but I can't seem to make it fit in with the rest of my expression, I'm looking to test for this:

```
<b>James Smith (ecg)</b>
```

But exclude this (the (ecg) is always lower case):

```
<b>JAMES SMITH (ecg)</b>
```

So far I have this:

```
<b>[A-z\s\W]+(\(ecg\))?\W?<\/b>
```

Which works but will also match if it's all in caps or all in lower case.
I tried this but it's still matching everything:

```
<b>(.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)[A-z\s\W]+(\(ecg\))?\W?<\/b>
```

Comment: `<b>\s*(?:[A-Z]+\s*[a-z]|[a-z]+\s*[A-Z])[\sA-Za-z]*(\(ecg\))?[^\w<]?<\/b>`? What can there be before `(ecg)`? What can be after?

Comment: Before (ecg) there is a space and 1 or more words with a mixture of upper and lower case letters and afer (ecg) there is </b>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
<b>(?=[A-Z\s]*[a-z])(?=[a-z\s]*[A-Z])[\sA-Za-z]*(?:\(ecg\))?<\/b>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZ3wbi/1)

**Details**

- `<b>` - a `<b>` text
- `(?=[A-Z\s]*[a-z])` - after 0 or more uppercase letters or whitespaces, there must be at least one lowercase letter
- `(?=[a-z\s]*[A-Z])` - after 0 or more lowercase letters or whitespaces, there must be at least one uppercase letter
- `[\sA-Za-z]*` - zero or more letters/whitespaces
- `(?:\(ecg\))?` - an optional `(ecg)` text
- `<\/b>` - a `</b>` text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR condition, checking for a lowercase letter followed by any number of other characters and an uppercase letter, OR, an uppercase letter followed by any number of other characters and at least one lowercase letter.

```
(([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])) \(ecg\)
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/eTG56K/2)

Comment: This still picks up TEST (ecg).

Comment: @user2096512 updated to account for your (ecg) requirement